# My constructor is not working as expected due to some error in data types and I cannot figure out why

Tags: java, android, constructor

```
public void Question(int resID, Boolean answer){
    this.mTextResId = resID;
    this.mAnswerTrue = answer;
}
```

This is a constructor I have for a class and then I am trying to build a question like this:

```
private Question q1 = new Question(R.string.question_americas, true);
```

and it gives me an error as follows:

> Question() in Question cannot be applied to (int, Boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at oracle documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for better understanding of constructor.

> A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from the class blueprint. Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type

In your case, you have wrongly added `void` as return type for constructor method.

For example, `Bicycle` has one constructor:

```
public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
    gear = startGear;
    cadence = startCadence;
    speed = startSpeed;
}
```

To create a new `Bicycle` object called `myBike`, a constructor is called by the new operator:

```
Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);
```

`new Bicycle(30, 0, 8)` creates space in memory for the object and initializes its fields.

***Following above example, your constructor should be***

```
public Question(int resID, Boolean answer){
    this.mTextResId = resID;
    this.mAnswerTrue = answer;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void Question(int resID, Boolean answer)
```

is not a constructor.

```
public Question(int resID, Boolean answer)
```

is a constructor.

Adding the `void` return type makes it a regular method instead of a constructor, which is why the compiler only finds the default parameter-less constructor `Question()` when you try to instantiate your class.

Comment: GOT IT! Thanks a lot!